# Creating links for elements with a particular class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I wrap every element belonging to a particular class with a link that is built from the text inside the div? What I mean is that I would like to turn:

```
<foo class="my-class>sometext</foo>
```

into

```
<a href="path/sometext" ><foo class="my-class>sometext</foo></a>
```

Url encoding characters would also be nice, but can be ignored for now if necessary.

**EDIT**: Just to clarify, the path depends on the text within the element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`jQuery.wrap()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/wrap) for the simple case:

```
$(".my-class").wrap("<a href='path/sometext'></a>");
```

To process text inside:

```
$(".my-class").each(function() {
  var txt = $(this).text();
  var link = $("<a></a>").attr("href", "path/" + txt);
  $(this).wrap(link[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".my-class").each(function(){
  var thisText = $(this).text();
  $(this).wrap("<a></a>").attr("href","path/"+thisText);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can wrap them inside anchor element like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".my-class").each(function(){
           var hr="path/"+$(this).text();
           $(this).wrap("<a href='"+hr+"'></a>");
   });
});
```

if you are opening links in same page itself then easier way than modifying dom to wrap elements inside anchor is to define css for the elements so that they look like links then handle click event:

```
$(".my-class").click(function(){
     window.location.href="path/"+$(this).text();
});
```

Comment: Be careful with $(this).html(). Better to use $(this).text() to avoid any formatting tags getting included.

Answer (score 0):

This ought to do it:

```
$('foo.my-class').each(function() {
  var element = $(this);
  var text = element.html(); // or .text() or .val()
  element.wrap('<a href="path/' + text + '"></a>');
});
```

Comment: I think you meant $(element) instead of $element.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("foo.my-class").each(function(){
  var foo = $(this);
  foo.wrap("<a href='path/" + foo.Text() +"'>");
});
```